# AWS ElasticSearch - restrict or filter data in Kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-iam

I have a managed ElasticSearch set up in AWS. I have researched how to apply resource or iam policies to restrict access to es domains, etc. However, what I was looking to do was possibly filter what an app team can see in the included Kibana dashboard based upon an iam policy.

Is there some way to possibly apply a policy that would allow me to restrict Kibana data access to certain groups/roles/users? I have not seen such a solution but wanted to make sure I'm not missing something.